# The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable when trying to mock

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am trying to test a bit of code I have:

```
public async Task<Sortation> SaveAsync(Sortation sortation)
{
    if (sortation.Id == 0)
    {
        var sortations = await ListAsync(sortation.CategoryId);
        sortation.Order = sortations.Count;
        _sortationService.Create(sortation);
    }
    else
    {
        _sortationService.Update(sortation);
    }

    await _sortationService.SaveChangesAsync();

    return sortation;
}
```

The **ListAsync** method is causing me an issue.
I set up my test like this:

```
[Test]
public async Task ShouldHaveOrderOfZero()
{
    // Assemble
    const string categoryId = "cameras";
    var services = SortationContext.GivenServices();
    var sortationProvider = services.WhenGetSortationProvider();
    var sortations = new List<Sortation>();
    var sortation = new Sortation { CategoryId = categoryId };

    services.MockSortationService.Setup(x => x.List()).Returns(sortations.AsQueryable);

    // Act
    await sortationProvider.SaveAsync(sortation);

    // Assert
    sortation.Order.Should().Be(0);
}
```

And when I run this, I get this error:

> Message: System.InvalidOperationException : The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

According to this: [Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169597/only-sources-that-implement-iasyncenumerable-can-be-used-for-entity-framework-as/39169756) I need to add EF to my UnitTest project, which I did.
But the error still persists.

The **ListAsync** method looks like this:

```
public async Task<List<Sortation>> ListAsync(string categoryId, params string[] includes) => 
    await _sortationService.List(includes).Where(m => m.CategoryId.Equals(categoryId)).ToListAsync();
```

Does anyone know how I can stop this error from happening?

Comment: ORMs like EF aren't a good fit for mocking and unit tests, frankly; I'm also of the opinion that even if it was: unit tests of DAL code *just isn't useful* (it gives a *very* false sense of security, to the point of being virtually useless to my tastes - albeit subjective) - I'd be *way* more interested in an integration test here, but that means: no mocks

Comment: Can you show more of the provider class being tested. including dependencies. You may have a leaky abstraction.

Answer (score 9):

In my case the exception was caused by using the wrong ToListAsync extension.

It came from:

using System.Data.Entity;
instead of

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
Changing the namespace fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if question is still actual, but still. I agree with Mark's comment, however here is an example, that works for me. I added some reasonable stub implementation for mentioned class, because there are not enouch details in question. I can be wrong in my assumptions:

```
[Test]
public async Task ShouldHaveOrderOfZero()
{
    // Assemble
    const string categoryId = "cameras";
    var services = SortationContext.GivenServices();
    var sortationProvider = services.WhenGetSortationProvider();
    var sortations = new List<Sortation>();
    var sortation = new Sortation { CategoryId = categoryId };

    // the key moq configuration here
    services.MockSortationService.Setup(x => x.ListAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(sortations));

    // Act
    await sortationProvider.SaveAsync(sortation);

    // Assert
    sortation.Order.Should().Be(0);
}

public class SortationProvider
{
    private SortationService _sortationService;

    public SortationProvider()
    {
        _sortationService = new SortationService();
    }

    public async Task<Sortation> SaveAsync(Sortation sortation)
    {
        if (sortation.Id == 0)
        {
            var sortations = await ListAsync(sortation.CategoryId);
            sortation.Order = sortations.Count;
            _sortationService.Create(sortation);
        }
        else
        {
            _sortationService.Update(sortation);
        }

        await _sortationService.SaveChangesAsync();

        return sortation;
    }

    // should be virtual
    public virtual async Task<List<Sortation>> ListAsync(string categoryId, params string[] includes) =>
        await _sortationService.List(includes).Where(m => m.CategoryId.Equals(categoryId)).ToListAsync();

}

public class SortationContext
{
    public static Services GivenServices()
    {
        return new Services();
    }
}

public class Services
{
    public Services()
    {
        MockSortationService = new Mock<SortationProvider>();
    }

    public SortationProvider WhenGetSortationProvider()
    {
        return MockSortationService.Object;
    }

    public Mock<SortationProvider> MockSortationService { get; set; }
}

internal class SortationService
{
    public void Create(Sortation sortation)
    {

    }

    public void Update(Sortation sortation)
    {

    }

    public Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public DbSet<Sortation> List(string[] includes)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Sortation
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

The main change is in line that contains `Setup` method. I made `ListAsync` method virtual also. The main assumption is that `List(string[] includes)` method returns `DbSet<Sortation>`. Hope it helps.