# .net Mocking ToListAsync() in repository is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mocking, moq

So I am trying to mock GetQueryable().ToListAsync() but I keep getting this error

"System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression ... Extension methods (here: EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions."

The mock code:

```
public async void Login_HappyPath_TokenAndRefreshToken(string email, string password)
{
    var _userManager = MockUserManager.MockManager<UserAccount>(true);

    _userManager.Setup(um => um.FindByEmailAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(() => new UserAccount { Email = email, Id = 1 });

    var userCompanies = new List<UserCompany> { new UserCompany { Id = 1, CompanyId = 1, UserId = 1 } };
    var queryableUserCompanies = userCompanies.AsQueryable();
    _mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetQueryable<UserCompany>()).Returns(queryableUserCompanies);
    _mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetQueryable<UserCompany>().ToListAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(userCompanies);

    var result = await userService.LoginAsync(new UserLoginDTO { Email = email, Password = password });
    Assert.NotNull(result);
}

public async Task<UserAuthDTO> LoginAsync(UserLoginDTO loginDTO)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginDTO.Email);

    if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginDTO.Password))
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Invalid email or password");

    var userCompanyIds = await _repo.GetQueryable<UserCompany>().AsNoTracking()
        .Where(c => c.UserId == user.Id)
        .Select(c => c.CompanyId)
        .ToListAsync();

    //I use them to generate token
    
    return new UserAuthDTO {...};
}
```

I also added the extension in the test project but it didn't work

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static async Task<List<TSource>> ToListAsync<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var list = new List<TSource>();

        await foreach (var element in source.AsAsyncEnumerable().WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
        {
            list.Add(element);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to mock it? Surely as you've already mocked the queryable then you can just let the code that you're testing handle the .ToList()?

Comment: This reason by the way is that 'ToListAsync' is an extension method. You can't mock extension methods

Comment: I can't share my code since it is outside the scop of the question but I assure you I need to mock ToListAsync() in order for the test to run

Comment: It's not outside the scope of the question. A minimum reproducible example is always beneficial :-)

Comment: Adding an extension is not the answer, I meant `ToListAsync` is an extension method whose internals need to be mocked. If you are using a `List<User>`, it will have the implementation for this method, you do not need to mock further. Please provide a complete reproducible example as mentioned above for a complete solution.

Comment: What is the type of `_mockRepo`?

Comment: I base repository .....

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>() where T : class
        {
            return this.DbContext.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
        }

Comment: I think if you comment the line where you mock the object for the `ToListAsync` method, it should work. This is because `x.GetQueryable<UserCompany>()` returns a `List<T>` object, which contains the definition for `ToListAsync` and does not require further mocking.

Comment: @Fahad I tried, it gives the error "    System.InvalidOperationException : The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncEnumerable<System.Int32>'. Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
"

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52220474/1746998?

Comment: @Fahad can you please remove ur answer, I will delete the question and reask it in another form

Answer (score 3):

`EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync` is an extension method that cannot be mocked. You can check the implementation of the extension method below and try mocking the internals instead. You can do this using any .NET decompiler such as dotPeek, ILSpy, etc.

```
public static async Task<List<TSource>> ToListAsync<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var list = new List<TSource>();
    await foreach (var element in source.AsAsyncEnumerable().WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
    {
        list.Add(element);
    }

    return list;
}

public static IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> AsAsyncEnumerable<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source) {
    Check.NotNull(source, nameof(source));

    if (source is IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> asyncEnumerable)
    {
        return asyncEnumerable;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException(CoreStrings.IQueryableNotAsync(typeof(TSource))); 
}
```

Comment: can you please show me how to call this mock method in my unit test?

Comment: please what is Check.NotNull?

Comment: didn't work :'(

Comment: Please give a reproducible example of the code as well. Otherwise we're just guessing

Comment: I edited the question with the code sample @scottdavidwalker